# assigning entire column of data to specific column of an array in vba

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I have an excel workbook in which I am dealing with large amounts of data. Roughly 5000 columns and 1000 rows at this point, but this will grow. I have defined and array in the following way

```
ReDim arr(1 To numRows, 1 To lastcol3)
```

If I use a double for loop in the following manner i can populate the entire array and it works:

```
For r = 1 To lastcol3
  For i = 1 To numRows
    arr(i, r) = ws1.Cells(i, 11)
  Next
Next
```

where ws1 is the worksheet in question and 11 is the column of data from which I want to take the data (changes with every value of r). This method works but takes a huge amount of time as it is required to loop through every row of data.

I was wondering if there is a method to, for every value of r, assign column 11 to the corresponding column "r" within the array. This will ensure that the code only need to loop through r, not i aswell?

I have searched a lot online but cannot seem to find a way of defining a specific column within an array and make it equal to a range of data.

If you require further clarification or a copy of the code please let me know.

Comment: WARNING a if you want to keep the information when you redim the array with preserve option set, you can only resize the last listed dimension of the array.  The may or may not be useful to you but thought I would mention it since I ran into this issue.

Comment: There are many posts about **loading ranges value to memory**, without need to define the size. You can do something like `Dim oValues as Variant: oValues = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Value` This loads all the values of used range including empty ones to memory. Use `LBound/UBound(oValues,1/2)` to retrieve boundaries: 1: rows, 2: cols

Answer (score 1):

As it looks to me, you are just going for values. However, every interaction with the worksheet is much slower than interactions between variables. Either use a helper variable to do it your way:

```
Dim xxx As Variant
xxx = ws1.Cells(i, 11).Resize(numRows, 1).Value
For r = 1 To lastcol3
  For i = 1 To numRows
    arr(i, r) = xxx(i, 1)
  Next
Next
```

Or to be even faster go with the `()()` option like this:

```
ReDim arr(1 To lastcol3)
Dim xxx As Variant
xxx = Application.Transpose(ws1.Cells(i, 11).Resize(numRows, 1).Value)
For r = 1 To lastcol3
  arr(r) = xxx
Next
```

but to get a value, you need to address it like `arr(r)(i)` which may be confusing at the beginning. But that also depends on what you are going to do later.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Please forgive me for not quite following, I am relatively new to vba and still finding my feet.

Although you method appears to work, it still requires me to iterate through all the rows "i" if I am not mistaken? I have tried it and it still runs very slowly.

I would like to create an array that is 1000 rows by 5000 columns. Every time I increase the value of r, the column of data changes and I want that column of data added  to the array from r = 1 To lastcol3, without having to go row by row.

Have I misunderstood your explanation and this is what it does?

Comment: To really be helpful, it would be good to know for what reason you need 5000+ times the same column? As in the question `arr(i, r) = ws1.Cells(i, 11)` all the 5k columns of your array hold exactly the same data which does not make sense to us. Maybe a different approach will be more helpful then just speeding up 1 sniped of your code...

Comment: Sorry, that is my fault for explaining poorly. Although the column itself remains the same, its content changes for every value of r. I have another array built into the code. As r changes, a identifying name on worksheet ws1 changes, and this in turn causes the INDEX MATCH function in the column in question to generate different results. Each iteration of the column corresponds to a unique system, but I need to bring all the data for each system together

Comment: Then you should post the whole code at codereview.stackexchange.com to get the best answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign an array directly from a range, without looping. The array type must be variant.

e.g.

```
dim myArr() as Variant
dim myRng as Range

Set myRng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:Z100")
myArr = myRng.Value
'... do stuff with myArr

Set myRng = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:Z100")
myRng.Value = myArr
```

[Chip Pearson](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/vbaarrays.htm) has lot of useful array handling routines.